# Wondering about a very simple construction

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, neo-latin

all—I find myself scratching my head over a very simple neo-Latin construction. Saint Lawrence writes: "tam vili pendendus est Christus ? tam parvi faciendus ?"

For sense, I want to parse *pendendus* as a future passive participle/gerundive from
*pendere* (third conjugation), to weigh out and hence more broadly to value. But that seems to virtually always take a genitive of value, and *vili* must be either an ablative or a dative.

So, perhaps *pendendus* comes from *pend**e**re* (second conjugation), which often takes an ablative. "Is Christ to be hung from such a cheap thing"? This comes after a passage discussing how Christ was placed in a manger, rather than some fancier place, so perhaps it has less to do with value and more with positioning?

Have I misunderstood the sentence or is it possible that, in later Latin, other cases were employed with *pendere*?

With *faciendus*, we've got a garden-variety genitive of value (I think): to be esteemed so little. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, *vīlī* ought to mean 'for cheap' and go with verbs like *vēndere, emere* 'to sell, buy'; *pendere* 'to value', just like *facere,* goes with the genitive  of very few words: *magnī, minōris, nihilī, floccī.* These are genitives of value, as you say.

It seems that what we have here instead is the medieval-only compound verb [***vīlipendere***](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/vilipendere) 'to value lightly, think little of, to slight'. I would regard the separate writing in Corpus Corporum as incorrect word division due to reanalysis; if it appears in the manuscripts, then the mistake is due to the scribe.

The verb might derive from the phrase *vīle pendere* where the verb is used transitively and means 'to think to be [of little value]'; however if you hit the "Inverse" switch under Logeion's logo, you'll find a whole host of parallel compound formations with *-pendere* including a gem like *reparvipendere.* This verb then is probably formed to the same highly-productive pattern.

What about those two *tam* - don't they modify the adjectives *vili* and *parvi* to mean 'so cheap, so little', meaning the writer treated it as a phrase? It's possible, but if so, the writer probably felt they were lexicalised adverbs and not standalone case forms, because the two cases are different but fixed; both appear with the same *pendere* in medieval Latin, but neither the gen. *vīlis* nor the abl. *parvō* do. However, it's possible that *tam* simply modifies the entire compound verb to mean 'in such a manner, like that' instead of meaning 'to such a degree' as an adj./adv. modifier. For this use see [L&S *tam*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/tam) under **II.B.3** 'With verbs'.

Comment: Of course, productive pendere makes sense. Medieval orthography can be very inconsistent regarding compound words. Sometimes you even see enclitics like ne and ve written separately.

Comment: @Kingshorsey Very much so, but enclitics and proclitics (prepositions) are spaced arbitrarily based on whether the writer considers phonetic or lexical word as the basis - this ambiguity was no different with the Romans and the same goes for modern languages. But separating the elements of lexical+lexical compounds means the writer considers it a syntactic phrase with the first word a standalone lexeme. And it seems to me this is only possible when they erroneously analyse *vili* as the ablative of *vīlis;* you wouldn't expect a separate *privi legium* or *primo genitus.* Hence I say "mistake"

Answer (score 3):

Searching for "vili pend*" in [Corpus Corporum](https://www.mlat.uzh.ch/browser?path=MLS/) yielded several hits from several medieval authors. However, some of these same authors continue to use the genitive with other words, e.g., parvi pendebat. I don't have an answer for why this construction occurs, but at least you know it's not just a grammatical idiosyncrasy of your author.